# is this correct re returning a date re memory management?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

is this correct re returning a date re memory management?

The assumption here I have is I want to return a date back to the caller, but I don't want the caller to be able to be change the date and impact the method's date, hence I thought I would return a copy.

So the code in the method I have is:

```
- (NSDate*)dateForMyTest {
     return [[self.endDate copy] autorelease];
}
```

I was assuming I have to autorelease it so the caller doesn't have to, as they would not have called an init/copy/etc themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may work, but creating a copy is not necessary. `NSDate` is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and cannot be edited later.

This should suffice...

```
- (NSDate*)dateForMyTest {
     return self.endDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, as far as it goes. But note that NSDate is immutable, so there is really no reason not to just return `self.endDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. Because the method name didn't include init/copy/new, you should autorelease.

Answer (score 0):

The copy autorelease may be needed if the app is using nsoperations/threads, etc. But you may be already thread safer - or not: When you use

```
return self.endDate
```

any number of things could be happening, depending on how the property was set up. Was it

```
 @property (retain) endDate;
```

, or the more common, faster and less thread safe

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) endDate;
```

It is as complicated as you like!

[What's the difference between the atomic and nonatomic attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)